# SSH connection in C++ under Linux

Tags: c++, ssh

I am coding a simple networking tool in C++ that should be working under unix/linux operating systems. 
I need to make SSH connection in C++, i.e. C++ SSH client ? 
And don't forget - Linux, so don't point me to msdn.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My question is more than clear: Making SHH client in C++ under linux ? How to do it ?

Comment: Which functionality do you need?

A good point to start is the collection of libssh2 examples - but:
libssh2 isn't a real (nice) C++ lib - IMHO it's just a bunch of C functions.

But it should be quite easy to build a C++ API by simple wrapper classes...

greetz,
Chris

Comment: Here the links to the libssh2 examples:

http://libssh2.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libssh2/libssh2/example/simple/

and a simple scp example:
http://libssh2.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libssh2/libssh2/example/simple/scp.c?revision=1.12&view=markup

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives to libssh2 are:

Commercial and free licensing:

http://www.netsieben.com/products/ssh/#licensing

Only commercial

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ssh-sftp-c++.asp

Answer (score 0):

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

You can download the source for putty here. Should give you a good start.

Comment: yeah thanks i saw the openssh source too, but didn't help me so much - i need someone to point me at the libraries.